# error in getting latitude and longitude from android device

Tags: android, google-maps

Here is my code to display Login user on google map and getting user location details(i.e latitude and longitude)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // Creating location manager and location classes instances
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
     location = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
     CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).zoom(9).build();

googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

.tried by debugging 
here able to display user on map done successfully but for getting location details getting null poiner exception,i am working on android mobile ( settings configured  ) but i am not getting why null pointer exception.suggest me suitable solution.(here using wifi connection. )

Answer (score 1):

you probably do not have a location at the time you call `getLastKnownLocation` which would be why you are getting null. so before you use the location object you should check to make sure it is not null. for example `if(location != null)`

you should probably look at using the new [Location API](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) or even the built in google map location manager as they get better results

Comment: tried that condition location is null,following u r link ,it is little difficult ,could you suggest easy way to get location details.http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: the new location API is not difficult at all just follow the tutorial and you will see that it is easy and much better because you know when you can request a location and not have to worry about what provider to use. it cuts out a lot of code that is use to manage the location provider

Comment: yes i know that is what you are using. if you dont want to use the location api then you can use the map location manager but then you have to have a blue dot on the map that shows your location instead. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location

Answer (score 1):

A nice gps tracker guide: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Just needed to add this.mLocation = location in onLocationChanged

---

googleMap can be null, of view has not been fully created.

location can be null if GPS is not enabled on phone.

Search for and follow some guides on the subject.

Comment: Yo man Google map working fine ,able to display user on map also ,problem in getting location only.

Comment: Ok, just looks abit fragile to me, then try and search for GPSTracker android. There is a tutorial that nicely wrap location into a single, easy to use, class.

Comment: i.e google maps first version ,i am using googlemaps v2.and i am following that site too.

Comment: fair enough. I added link to the guide i was talking about in answer.

Comment: No problemo. Happy coding